# Context added to translation tags do not pull through correctly to extracted translations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

I'm using [`react-i18n`](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next) to translate a web app.

I'm extracting translations from the tags I add to a JSON file using [`babel-plugin-i18next-extract`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-i18next-extract).

I define a tag like so in my component:

```
{t("Departure", { context: "air" })}
{t("Departure", { context: "rail" })}
```

But in my extracted translations folder it comes through as:

```
"Departure": "",
"Departure_female": "",
"Departure_male": "",
```

It seems the extracted translation is ignoring the context and simply adding `_male` and `_female` is this a bug with `babel-plugin-i18next-extract`

Comment: The context option expects an array of strings, could that be the issue?

Comment: Having context as an array results in the translation not being extracted. The documentation here suggests the context is a string not an array: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/context

Answer (score 0):

`babel-plugin-i18next-extract` indeed doesn't extract the value of context keys because they are more likely to be variables and therfore parsing them would be pointless most of the time. One solution would be to use [comment hints](https://i18next-extract.netlify.com/#/comment-hints?id=explicitly-specify-contexts-for-a-key):

```
{/* i18next-extract-mark-context-next-line ["air"] */}
{t("Departure", { context: "air" })}

{/* i18next-extract-mark-context-next-line ["rail"] */}
{t("Departure", { context: "rail" })}
```

There's an open issue about this: https://github.com/gilbsgilbs/babel-plugin-i18next-extract/issues/121